# Type of appointment to take to close a passport application?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india

My hometown is in West Bengal, India and currently I am staying in Gurugram.

I applied for a passport in Gurugram and the officials have put it on hold as they are asking me to come up with another address proof rather than the rent agreement which I don't have. So I want to close this application for that I just wanted to know which type of appointment I have to take as there are two options:

```
appointment for application submission
```

or

```
appointment for enquiry
```

Comment: I have no experience with the Indian passport authority, so this is not posted as an Answer. But logically speaking, the first alternative (Appt for Submission) is clearly not what you want to do. The second alternative (Appt for Enquiry) is closer, as you do in fact have an Enquiry: "How do I cancel or close my application?" Of these two, I'd choose the second.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you can show photo passbooks issued by nationalized banks as proof of address.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to not have to go in. You could go to the place, wait in line for an appointment etc....

However, there's a toll free helpline to get an instant answer on this: 1800 258 1800

They're open Monday to Friday – 9:30 AM to 4:30 PM.

You can also email them on passportggn@gmail.com

Website: www.passportindia.gov.in/